# My html page is cutting on mobile screen and scroll bar on x-axis automatically becomes active. What is the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on my porfolio. My project section html page is cutting on mobile screen and scroll bar on x-axis automatically becomes active. What is the issue?.

**UI:**
User Interface Link

[image: User Interface Link]

OR

https://hamzailyas-portfolio-237.web.app/portfolio/projects.html

**HTML code:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/639QQ.png]

**CSS code:**

```
.project-container {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 40px 22px;
}

#row {
    margin-top: -100px !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.project-card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 70px 20px !important;
    min-width: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
}

.project-card a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.project-card:hover {
    background: crimson;
    color: white !important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease !important;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.project-card:hover a {
    color: white !important;
}

.project-card h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.project-card p {
    font-size: larger;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.project-card p img {
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

/* @media only screen and (min-width: 651px) and (max-width: 1100px) { 
    .project-container {
        margin-right: 100px;
    }        
} */

@media screen and (max-width: 1319px) {
    .project-card img {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .project-container {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .project-container {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .project-container {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .project-card img {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .project-card img {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .project-card {
        padding: 60px 10px !important;
        font-size: smaller;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for contributing @web Rocker, Rabi Kanwal and Hemant Kumar. Every one's code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a scroll bar on the x axis that is the issue, try:

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have tried overflow-x: hidden; but it's not working. Open this link in your phone than you can understand what is the problem.  https://hamzailyas-portfolio-237.web.app/portfolio/projects.html

Comment: I viewed the page on mobile and did not see any "cutting" or scroll bar on the x axis

Comment: Other pages of this website are responsive but only this page is making issue. I think the problem is in project-container or project-card styling.

Comment: Could you post a photo of the problem

Comment: check on small sreen size phone. check it on 360px width.

Comment: I have posted the image. Check this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnKWN.png

Comment: Is this image from a phone or from something like google chrome dev tools responsive view?

Comment: This image is from  google chrome dev tools responsive view, but i have also checked it on phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code to make the perfect layout for Desktop & Small Devices. By doing this way you will not find any scrollbar.

```
#row {
    display: flex;
    padding: 15px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -100px !important;
}
.project-container {
    padding: 15px;
    flex: 0 0 33.333%;
    max-width: 33.333%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.project-card {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 70px 20px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .project-container {
        flex: 0 0 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
    .project-container {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this its will help on your current css. i added this and its work

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
.project-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px 0px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
.project-card {
    margin: 0px 15px;
}
.project-card a {
    word-break: break-all;
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i add this and its works

Answer (score 0):

[image: "height"]

[image: "Flex wrap in p "]

"Height = auto, it gives flexibility to height of the component"

"Add p = flex-wrap", which helps to tighten the paragraph, which is out of the box.